# template member function is instantiated only if called

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions

Why there is an error in this code:

```
template <typename T>
    class CLs{
        public:
        void print(T* p){ p->print(); }
    };

    void main() {
        CLs<int> c1; // compilation OK
        CLs<double> c2; // compilation OK
        double d=3;
        c2.print(&d);
    }
```

My lecturer said there is an error in the `c2.print(&d);` line:

`Compilation Error: Member function is instantiated only if called.`

What does he mean?

Comment: variable `d` is of type `double` so when you call `c2.print(&d)` in the body of the function is like calling `d.print()` but d is a concrete type and doesn't have a member function `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member functions for class templates are only actually generated if they are used. This is an important part of templates which prevents unnecessary code bloat and allows support of types which don't fulfil the entire implicit contract for a template, but are sufficient for usage.

Your declarations of `CLs<T>` variables compile cleanly because the `print` function isn't compiled until it is used. `c2.print(&d)` fails to compile, because it causes the instantiation of `CLs<double>::print`, which is ill-formed.